# Docker making image with Dockerfile and permanent helper files in its volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

New to Docker.

Is there a possible way to create docker image with some helper files which will be permanent in the volume of the image under container certain folder, without dependency to copy them each build time from the host machine where we build the image, since I may have host which down't contain these files.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create first `base` image where these files will be placed. And you need to push this image to repository. After it you can create other images based on first image.

I try to explain idea in example.

Base image has *Dockerfile*

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
...
COPY /my_big_files /my_big_files/
```

Build this image with tag `my_image_with_files:latest` and push it to repository

Other images based on first image can be buit on the another PC.

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM my_image_with_files:latest
...
RUN ls /by_big_files/ # <- your files already there!
```

Comment: Does docker have local repositories that I can simulate a push, and debug the functionality I want on the local as what you mentioned here?

Comment: You can try this way without pushing image on the single PC because Docker creates local image storage quietly.

Comment: Also if you want to try build second image on the another pc you can use [official docker repository](http://hub.docker.com). Or you can simply [archive](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) first image to `tar.gz` file, transfer it to another pc and unpack it.